# dart postgres package - select statement throws exception - PostgresSQLSeverity.error 42601

Tags: postgresql, flutter, dart

I am trying the postgres package for Dart. Running this query is giving me a severity exxeption.

The method in the snip is receiving a list of contacts and each contact do have the % sign prefixed to it, which means I am using like inside of the IN clause. Basically I want matching contacts from the database that has the phone number value of the contacts in the phone number column.

[image]

Comment: What is `contacts`? `IN` works on a subquery or `ROW/ARRAY`.

Comment: This is the way how the contacts are received in side the method [%91000000000, %7780000000, %6720000000, %4160000000, %7790000000]. I am also trying this final results = await postgresConnection.query(
        "SELECT phone_number FROM public.users WHERE phone_number ilike any(array[@contacts])",
        substitutionValues: {"contacts": contacts}); it doesn't give any results.

Comment: Well this is going to come down to how the driver handles the conversion to Postgres array. I don't use Dart, but a quick search found this [Dart Pg driver](https://pub.dev/documentation/postgresql2/latest/). See under Notes, 'Substitution of Array types'. If that is not the driver you are using then you will need to go to the docs for whatever you are using and see how it handles arrays.

Comment: Had a look to the link, tried out a few things, still it is not resolved.

Comment: Then this is going to need someone versed in Dart to answer. Or you could ask on one of the other Dart support places, see here [Community](https://dart.dev/community).

Comment: Dart tag is already there in this post

Comment: Yes, but this is not the only place Dart users hang out. Given that none have actually responded it might be a good idea to try some of the other support options.